# How to count the number of orders in the first hour in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say have a table like:

```
DateTime - When the order was placed
CustomerId - The id of the customer
<other fields>
```

How do I create a query that will tell me the total number of orders a customer placed in the hour after creating their first order.

I'm currently finding the first order per customer, joining it back to the original table, and doing a `countif` but wondering if there is a way to do it in a single step.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Standard SQL, you can use logic like this:

```
select customerid, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(datetime) over (partition by customerid) as min_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where datetime < min_datetime + interval '1 hour'
group by customerid;
```

Date/time functions differ significantly among databases, but this general structure should work in almost every database.

Comment: ISO/ANSI SQL standard has the syntax `interval '1' hour`.